# How do I access each element?

Tags: javascript, html

For example if I would like to store *"CS 484"* and *"12:00"* in separate variables?

This is the data:

```
[{"ClassName":"CS484","Days":["Tuesday","Thursday"],"StartTime":"12:00","EndTime":"13:15"}]
```

Comment: Are you accessing the data in JavaScript or PHP? You tagged both.

Comment: Just Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have your data mapped to a variable, simply access the first index of the array (with `[0]`), then access the key of the object.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
const data = [{"ClassName":"CS484","Days":["Tuesday","Thursday"],"StartTime":"12:00","EndTime":"13:15"}];

const className = data[0].ClassName;
const startTime = data[0].StartTime;

console.log(className, startTime);
```

Comment: when i print className through alert it says undefined

Comment: var datavalues = localStorage.getItem('MyClassSchedule');
                 
               
                      const className = datavalues[0].ClassName;
                      const startTime = datavalues[0].StartTime;

                      alert(className);